# Logstash not starting up

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to start logstash 5.4 on my linux rhel 6 server but i'm getting the following message:

> WARNING: Default JAVA_OPTS will be overridden by the JAVA_OPTS defined in the environment. Environment JAVA_OPTS are -Xms1G .Xmx64G
>   Error: Could not find or load main class .Xmx64G

Following is my logstash.conf in which I'm try to ingest data from sqlserver

```
    input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://9.37.92.72:1433;databaseName=KaiserPermanente;"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "passw0rd!"
    statement => "select * from IEVDIncident ;"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "kaiserpermanente"
  }
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

Please tell me how can I resolve this one. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're trying to assign 64g as maximum memory and you possibly don't have it available. Also, official recommendation from elastic is to limit max to 32GB which should not be more then half of available memory on your system.. so If you have 32GB of memory in your system you should assign 16GB to elastic maximum, also recommended to set initial and max to the same value. Check your jvm.options file. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-setting-files.html

Comment: how can I assign the memory to elastic search, do I have to set it in elasticsearch.yml, what is the syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` with value `-Xms1G .Xmx64G` so it overrides logstash options. You need to change your variable to `-Xms1G -Xmx64G`. Replace `.` with `-`.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Please refer to this page: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/.